# Issue with reading text file into numpy array using pandas reader

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, reader

I have a massive text file, a dummy version looks like this after skipping headers:

```
1444455        7        8        12 52 45 68 70

1356799        3        3        45 34 23 22 11
```

I would like to read this into a numpy array and np.loadtxt is working really slow. The name of the file is data.txt. Right now I am using:

```
u=pd.read_csv('data.txt',dtype=np.float16,header=3).values
```

I have played with the parameters to no avail. If I leave out the dtype I get a single long string of numbers for each row in my array. When I insert the dtype I get the error: invalid literal for float(). I believe there is also some confusion about the two types of separators I have in the text file (tabs and single spaces). How can I get this into a numpy array of shape (2,8).

Could any of you pros help? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need `delim_whitespace=True` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) if separator is whitespace and `header=None`:

Then cast to `float`:

```
u=pd.read_csv('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None).astype(float).values

print (u)
[[  1.44445500e+06   7.00000000e+00   8.00000000e+00   1.20000000e+01
    5.20000000e+01   4.50000000e+01   6.80000000e+01   7.00000000e+01]
 [  1.35679900e+06   3.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00   4.50000000e+01
    3.40000000e+01   2.30000000e+01   2.20000000e+01   1.10000000e+01]]
```

but there is `numpy.float64`:

```
u=pd.read_csv('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None).astype(float)

print (type(u.loc[0,0]))
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

If use `dtype=np.float16` get `inf`:

```
u=pd.read_csv('data.txt', dtype=np.float16, delim_whitespace=True, header=None).values
print (u)
[[ inf   7.   8.  12.  52.  45.  68.  70.]
 [ inf   3.   3.  45.  34.  23.  22.  11.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.